# Exclude does not work in filter

Tags: aem

Let us say, my project structure in AEM server is as follows-

/apps/myproject/components/compA

/apps/myproject/components/compB

And my project structure in SVN is as follows -

/apps/myproject/components/compA

/apps/myproject/components/compB

/apps/myproject/components/compC

Now, I want that compC should not be installed while installing package, hence I've added filter in pom.xml -

```
   <filter>
     <mode>update</mode>
       <root>/apps/myproject</root>
        <excludes>
        <exclude>/apps/myproject/components/compC(/.*)?</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
```

But it does not work, after package installation compC also gets installed. Please let me know if what is missing here.

Comment: If the filter is being added correctly while being packaged, then this configuration using an [update mode](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/importmode.html) will not delete an existing compC node. I've only used the filter being sourced using a `filterSource` element. e.g. `<filterSource>src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>`.

Comment: my requirement is not delete, requirement is not to install compC while installing package

Comment: When we install a package, all we're doing is adding/updating/removing nodes in the JCR tree. So if the compC already exists on that path in the repo, your filter config will not remove it.

Comment: perhaps my question is not clear enough or you did not get it correctly, compC does not exists in repo, it is within package and I do not install compC

Comment: I see. okay then try this pattern. `<exclude>.*/components/compC(/.*)?</exclude>`

Comment: this does not work, as per test it works only when root path is also same as exclude path, for example, if I mentioned root path as /apps/myproject/components/compC then excludes works properly which is not my requirment